# ¿Como tener acceso a un método declarado en una clase de java como 'Public Static Interface' desde un companion object de kotlin para android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm, static

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo un proyecto de Android, el cual lo estoy importando como librería en otro proyecto. Dicho proyecto que desde ahora le llamaré solamente como **librería**, esta escrito en java, ese proyecto ya esta terminado, funciona, no tengo por qué tocarlo.

Ahora, al yo importar la librería en mi proyecto de kotlin, declaro una clase central que utilizare como mediadora u organizadora, para acceder a ciertas clases y métodos que me interesan de la librería.

Hasta ahí todo bien. Declaro mi clase organizadora de la siguiente manera en mi clase de kotlin.

```
class TopApp : Application() {


    companion object {
        lateinit var usdkManage: TopUsdkManage
        lateinit var mApp: TopApp
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //mContext = applicationContext
        mApp = this

        //init
        usdkManage = TopUsdkManage.getInstance(mApp)
        usdkManage!!.init(this)

    }

}
```

Posteriormente cuento con la clase TopUsdkManage, que accedo a ella que se encuentra en la librería. Recordar que esta en java. Esta algo así:

```
public class TopUsdkManage {

    /*
    * Atributos, constructor, etc.
    */


    public void init(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
        /* Hace cosas el init, todo bien. **A este método SÍ tengo acceso.** */
    }

    public void unBindDeviceService(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
        /* Hace cosas el unBindDeviceService, todo bien. **A este método SÍ tengo acceso.** */
    }

    public void setmDeviceService(IBinder iBinder) {
        /* Hace cosas el setmDeviceService, todo bien. **A este método SÍ tengo acceso.** */
    }

    public static UnaInterface getPinpadManager(int type) {
        /* Hace cosas el getPinpadManager, todo bien. **A este método NO tengo acceso.** */
    }

}
```

Luego, intento hacer uso de dichos métodos de la siguiente forma en una clase de kotlin:

```
class OtraClase{
     fun mFuncion(){
          val mInterface: UnaInterface = TopApp.usdkManage.getPinpadManager(0)
     }
}
```

Y aquí es donde presento mi problema, el alcance de mi función getPinpadManager, pues no se implementa, a pesar de estar como metodo público y estático, pero los métodos de arriba que también son públicos, mas no estáticos, si tengo acceso a ellos. Supongo que tiene que ver con qué este método, getPinpadManager, regresa algo, en este caso una interface y ademas es estático.

Tengo ya rato buscando pero la verdad es que ni sé como buscar esto. Espero alguien tenga alguna experiencia relacionada. Lo agradeceré bastante.

UPDATE: Cabe mencionar que tengo un demo que utiliza dicha librería, el asunto es que ese demo esta en java 100%, y ahí sí funciona todo normal, por lo que estoy seguro que ha de ser algo de la compatibilidad de la JVM y Kotlin o me falte alguna etiqueta tipo '@JvmStatic' o algo por estilo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `getPinpadManager` es estático. Esto significa que no le pertenece a las instancias sino a la clase en sí misma. Lo que debes hacer es llamarlo usando la clase como receiver

```
class OtraClase{
     fun mFuncion(){
          val mInterface: UnaInterface = TopUsdkManage.getPinpadManager(0)
     }
}
```

Comment: Pues efectivamente, así funciona. Sinceramente aun no entiendo él por qué,  aun no comprendo bien el concepto de static en Java. Tendré que estudiarlo mejor. Gracias por contestar.